# При подключении скрипта спойлера, перестаёт работать скрипт слайдера

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть сайт, на котором около трёх лет стоял скрипт слайдера:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    var foto = <?php echo get_photo_for_slideshow(); ?>
    foto = jQuery.shuffle(foto);
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
        jQuery(".gallery img").fadeTo( 500, 0.5);
            jQuery(".gallery img").bind("mouseover",function(){
                jQuery(this).fadeTo(500,1);
            });
                jQuery(".gallery img").bind("mouseleave",function(){
                    jQuery(this).fadeTo(500,0.5);
                });
        jQuery(window).bind("resize",function(){
                var plotis = -1*Math.round(((2400-$(window).width())/2));
                $("#juosta ul ").css("margin-left",plotis+"px");
        });
        $.each(foto, function(index, value) { 
                $("#juosta ul").append("<li><img id='foto_"+index+"_1' src='/wp-content/plugins/sets/upload/"+value+"' style=\"opacity: 0\"/><img id='foto_"+index+"_2' src=\"/wp-content/plugins/sets/upload/"+value+"\" style=\"opacity: 0\" /></li>");
                var time = 500*(index+1);
                if(index == 0){
                    var plotis = -1*Math.round(((2400-$(window).width())/2));
                    $("#juosta ul").css("margin-left",plotis+"px");
                }
                jQuery(document).oneTime(time, function(){
                $("#foto_"+index+"_1").animate({
                    opacity: 1
                }, 500, function() {
                // Animation complete.
                });
            });
        });
        jQuery(document).everyTime(5000, "base", function(){
                foto = jQuery.shuffle(foto);
            var b = foto.shift();
            foto[foto.length] = b;
            //foto.reverse();
            $.each($(foto), function(index, value) { 
                var time = 1000*(index+1);
                $(document).oneTime(time, function(){
                if($("#foto_"+index+"_1").css("opacity")=="1"){
                // pirma foto matoma
                    $("#foto_"+index+"_1").animate({opacity: 0},1000);
                    $("#foto_"+index+"_2").attr("src","/wp-content/plugins/sets/upload/"+value).animate({opacity: 1},1000);
                }else{
                    // antra foto matoma
                    $("#foto_"+index+"_1").attr("src","/wp-content/plugins/sets/upload/"+value).animate({opacity: 1},1000);
                    $("#foto_"+index+"_2").animate({opacity: 0},1000);
                }
                });
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Теперь я хочу подключить скрипт спойлера:
`<script type="text/javascript"
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`
Когда я добавляю скрипт перед тегом  спойлер начинает работать, а вот слайдер пропадает. Помогите найти причину.

Comment: Без подробностей по слайдеру и спойлеру, помочь Вам никто не сможет. Но у Вас, однозначно, конфликт между скриптами. Смотрите консоль браузера, там наверняка есть ошибки.

Comment: решение для сохранения текущего функционала и нового - переписывать скрипт, либо старый, либо новый через `jQuery.noConflict()`.

Comment: У меня подозрение что там нет второй библиотеки. Вот собственно страница, спойлер увидите, а слайдер должен быть в большой полосе: tifani.by/kariera/rabota-v-restorane

Comment: Перенесите это в вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил таким образом, переместил оба кода в head и упорядочил в определённом порядке, методом тыка. Всем ответившим спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

скорее всего у вас уже подключен jquery другой версии - в следствии этого возникает конфликт между версиями

Comment: Скорей всего сдайдер завязан на старой jquery допусти версия 1.6 там клик можно было сделать через elem.live('click') но при подключение новой версии библиотеки live там вырезан итог у тебя не поддерживаются некоторые функции которые устарели уже.

Comment: А как мне быть теперь?

Comment: У меня подозрение что там нет второй библиотеки. Вот собственно страница, спойлер увидите, а слайдер должен быть в большой полосе:
http://www.tifani.by/kariera/rabota-v-restorane/

Comment: хм, действительно вроде как нету. Возможно изза Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined и вылетает. Эта ошибка возникает потому, что $.browser удалена из jQuery1.9. Есть методы обхода, но я бы посоветовал поискать какой-то другой подходящий плагин...

Answer (score 1):

С учетом вашей ссылки на проблемную страницу, видно следующее:

> Ошибка: jQuery.browser is undefined Источник:
>   http://www.tifani.by/wp-content/themes/tifani/js/jquery.timers.js
>   Строка: 152

Что не удивительно, `jQuery.browser` был [объявлен устаревшим](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) и удален из библиотеки с выходом версии 1.9, а вы подключаете *jQuery* версии 1.11. Либо подключайте *jQuery.migrate*, либо переписывайте *jquery.timers.js*